# Unable to implement flutter local notifications, please debug code

Tags: flutter

I tried the official documentation and also tried following a lot of different guides but somehow i am unable to be able to show a simple local notification on my app. I am confused with completely different lines of code being shown on different guides. My app runs fine without the local notification implementation.

It is a simple app which fetches some data from an API and should display a notification whenever any of the computed data is > 0.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future main() async {
  //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyWin App',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(
          //primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'CoWin paid vaccine availability for 18+'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('icons8_coronavirus_64.png');

    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
            macOS: null);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

    fetchAvailability();
    getData();
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    //Handle notification tapped logic here
  }

  int day = 0;
  int sumApolloGariahat = 0;
  int sumApolloBypass = 0;
  int sumWoodlands = 0;
  List<int> availableAtApolloBypass = [];
  List<int> availableAtApolloGariahat = [];
  List<int> availableAtWoodlands = [];

  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByDistrict?district_id=725&date=17-05-2021');

  Future<http.Response> fetchAvailability() {
    return http.get(url);
  }

  Future getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      Map decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

      var apolloGariahatID = decodedData['centers'][11]['center_id'];
      var apolloBypassID = decodedData['centers'][16]['center_id'];
      var woodlandsID = decodedData['centers'][23]['center_id'];

      for (day = 0;
          day < decodedData['centers'][12]['sessions'].length;
          day++) {
        availableAtApolloGariahat.add(decodedData['centers'][12]['sessions']
            [day]['available_capacity_dose1']);
      }

      for (day = 0;
          day < decodedData['centers'][16]['sessions'].length;
          day++) {
        availableAtApolloBypass.add(decodedData['centers'][16]['sessions'][day]
            ['available_capacity_dose1']);
      }

      for (day = 0;
          day < decodedData['centers'][27]['sessions'].length;
          day++) {
        availableAtWoodlands.add(decodedData['centers'][27]['sessions'][day]
            ['available_capacity_dose1']);
      }

      availableAtApolloGariahat.forEach((e) => sumApolloGariahat += e);
      availableAtApolloBypass.forEach((e) => sumApolloBypass += e);
      availableAtWoodlands.forEach((e) => sumWoodlands += e);

      print('Available at Apollo Gariahat: $sumApolloGariahat');
      print('Available at Apollo EM Bypass: $sumApolloBypass');
      print('Available at Woodlands: $sumWoodlands');
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  Future showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            showWhen: false);
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Available at Apollo Gariahat: $sumApolloGariahat',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            Text(
              'Available at Apollo EM Bypass: $sumApolloBypass',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            Text(
              'Available at Woodlands: $sumWoodlands',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: showNotification,
              child: Text('Show Notification'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with the initialisation of your plugin.

You have given your android settings as this.

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('icons8_coronavirus_64.png');
```

You have probably forgot to include this image asset directly in the `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder.

As mentioned in the documentation of `flutter_local_notifications`, for showing notification on android, all images need to be added into the `drawable` folder.

I have added my own `icon.png` into the `drawable` folder like this,

[image]

The, I used it in my initialization, like this

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('icon.png');
```

This fixed the issue for me and I can now see your sample notification.

Comment: Hey, i removed the .png extension and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: I see. Cool then. :)

Comment: Should we keep this answer or delete this ? I noticed this being asked in their github.